# How to add multiple smart contracts to remix?

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-deployment

How to add multiple smart contracts to remix? i have a project including several smart contracts such that they are inherited from each other. The question is how to add all of them to remix and then test each of them?

Comment: Question unclear. You want to import all the contracts in remix?

Comment: @Elisha Drion yes because there are several solidity files in a project such that some of them are inherited from another one

Comment: Well, you can just import them with the folder icon at top-left.

Answer (score 1):

You might find remixd interesting. It allows you to interact with your file system from Remix. So you will be able to access all your contract in remix.

From the [tutorial](https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_remixd_filesystem.html):

> Remixd can be globally installed using the following command: `npm
>   install -g remixd`.
>
> Then `remixd -s <absolute-path-to-the-shared-folder>` will start
>   Remixd and share the given folder.